# ¿ Los Atributos son "Necesarios"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Programadores, tengo una duda emergente, pero bastante elemental. En POO, podemos asignarle una serie de atributos a nuestras clases para moldear objetos a conveniencia, entendiendo esto, ¿es necesario crear variables por separado? o basta con asignarle atributos directamente a los métodos?

Comment: @static? es python3 brother, a penas empiezo en POO

Comment: `@staticmethod`, remueve los parentesis, señor por favor nunca pongas como excusas, no digas *apenas empiezo en POO*, ¿quieres que la calidad de mi comentario dependa de tu nivel o quieres aprender?, revisa la docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: ademas lea [ask], nunca coloque imagenes de sus código, coloquelo en la pregunta.

Comment: class C:
    @staticmethod
    def f(base,altura):
        formula = base * altura
        return formula
print(C.f(2,2))

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando por las diferencias entre *"atributos de clase"* y *"atributos de instancia"*? Por favor, aclara la pregunta y pon algún ejemplo ilustrando el problema.